# If the id of a row changes, how would I change the data for that particular row?

Tags: loops, row

I am a DBA of 6 months. I was a data analyst at one time, but that was long ago. I am needing to know is it possible in SQL Server 2008 R2 to make a date change as a particular row id changes? I have to recreate a sales import process. I always grab the max id for the previous date (getdate() - 1). I am currently doing this in FileMaker Pro Advanced 11.2, but my company is migrating from FileMaker Pro Advanced 11.2 to SQL Server 2008 R2. I am currently using SQL Server R2 to recreate the sales import process, but I just need to know how to write a code that would change the date field when the row id changes. I have attached a file (i wrote a result set using excel just as an example) to show you all what I am trying to accomplish. On Mondays, I always run the import for the previous Friday, Saturday, and Sunday. This is why I need to know when there is a change in ID, there will be a change in date (going back) I am pretty sure that I would have to use something like getdate() -2, getdate() - 3, but I need to know how to apply this as the Id changes. as the ID decreases, the date will go back a previous day with each change. Your help would be greatly appreciated. I have tried nearly everything and have worked on this for about 2 weeks but to no avail. I tried to put a picture on here but I do not have enough points. Here is what I am trying to do for example:

```
SalesID     SalesDate   
101         2/19/2012   
101         2/19/2012   
101         2/19/2012   
201         (I need for this date to be 2/18/2012), 
201         (I need for this date to be 2/18/2012)
301         (I need for this date to be 2/17/2012)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to set up a trigger, so that if a field is updated the data is told what it needs to update fields that you specify to.

See: [sql server trigger to update time field when there is real change in another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806120/sql-server-trigger-to-update-time-field-when-there-is-real-change-in-another-fie)